# Como retornar False en un map y no se complete el registro

Tags: javascript, html, condiciones, map

Estoy tomando un input para un registro de usuarios con localStorage y cuando hago un map en el primer if para ver si el email ya se encuentra registrado no me toma el Return False... aqui les muestro

```
botonRegistro.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
const nombre = inputNombre.value
const apellido = inputApellido.value
const email = inputEmail.value.toLowerCase()
const password1 = inputPassword1.value
const password2 = inputPassword2.value
usuarios.map((usuario) => {
  if (usuario.email === email) {
    alert("El email ya se encuentra registrado.")
    return false
  };
});
if (password1 != password2) {
    alert("Las contraseñas no coinciden.")
    return false
}
const nuevoUsuario = new Usuario( nombre, apellido, email, password1)
usuarios.push(nuevoUsuario)
localStorage.setItem('Usuario', JSON.stringify(usuarios))
alert("Gracias por registrarse")
location.href ="/index.html";
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu caso, estás queriendo verificar si un correo electrónico ya existe en el array de usuarios, pero el **`map()`** devuelve un nuevo array y no necesitas ese array para comprobar si el email existe, sino verificar si uno de sus elementos coincide con el email del input.

Entonces, otra solución sería iterar cada elemento del array **`usuarios`** con [**`for...of`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) y verificar que si en una de las iteraciones el email es igual al email de tu input, muestra el alert y retorna false, ejemplo:

```
for (const usuario of usuarios) {
  if (usuario.email === email) {
    alert("El email ya se encuentra registrado.");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La función `map` convierte una lista de objeto en otra lista de objetos, la entrada y la salida tienen una relación 1 a 1. Y no debería usarse como reemplazante de un for/foreach.

El `return false` que tienes en ese `map` es el retorno del map, no de la función (evento en este caso). Tu estas creando un nuevo array con la misma cantidad de elementos que el array `usuarios` y que en su interior tiene `false` cuando se cumple la condición y `undefined` cuando no.

La función que tu necesitas es [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) que básicamente te dice si es que existe algún elemento que cumple la condición dada.

```
if( usuarios.some( u => u.mail === email)){
   alert("El email ya se encuentra registrado.");
   return false;
}
```